# Keeping quotations as tuple members in Factor

Tags: factor-lang

I want to keep a quotation as a member of a tuple in Factor. But when I try to execute 'call' on it I get the error 'cannot apply call to a run-time computed value'. Note that marking the functions as 'inline' does nothing.

Sample code:

```
USING: accessors kernel ;
IN: stackoverflow

TUPLE: quottuple quot ;
C: <quottuple> quottuple

: call-quot ( quottuple -- result )
    quot>> call ; inline

: main ( -- )
    [ 1 ] <quottuple>
    call-quot drop ;

MAIN: main
```

Comment: Could you show some code of how you are trying to execute the quotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is the 'call(' word. That word requires you to specify the stack effect of the quotation, but as a result the quotation doesn't need to be known at compile time.

```
USING: accessors kernel ;
IN: stackoverflow

TUPLE: quottuple quot ;
C: <quottuple> quottuple

: call-quot ( quottuple -- result )
    quot>> call( -- result ) ;

: main ( -- )
    [ 1 ] <quottuple>
    call-quot drop ;

MAIN: main
```

Comment: You can use `infer` to get the stack effect of a quotation whose stack effect may not be known at compile time.